# How to add support for jquery's $.active variable in typescript

Tags: typescript

Using typescript I have the jquery definition file so it allows and helps me use jquery functions. But it doesn't seem to support the $.active variable. Perhaps because it's meant to be used internally inside of jquery. How do I write an interface for it? For now I'm using
`(<Any>, $).active`
to allow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I write an interface for it? For now I'm using (, $).active to allow it

create `globals.d.ts` with:

```
export interface JQuery {
  active: any;
}
```